# See latest diff for a file, without specifying a commit signature

Tags: git, command-line, diff, commit, sha1

In Git, is it possible to see the latest diff for a file without specifying a commit?

For instance, I've got a file called `hello.js`. It was last modified two commits ago. I could do the following to see those changes: `git diff a1b2c3^ hello.js` (note the caret, to indicate the "previous" diff).

But is there a way to do the same, but without specifying a commit? Like `git diff hello.js^` for instance? I know I can get the last commit for the file by doing `git log hello.js`, then look at the top commit for the signature. But I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to do all this.

Or is this not possible because Git is unable to see the last time a change was made to a file, without specifying a commit?

Comment: To clarify, you want to know: "for file F, regardless of whether the last change to it was when I just committed something a minute ago, or a change one more commit back yesterday, or a change 500 commits back, a year ago, show me the change"?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.

Answer (score 5):

There are several (well, it's git: probably very many :-) ) ways to do this but I think this one is the most straightforward: use `git log` and rely on what git calls "history simplification" (see [the `git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html#_history_simplification) for details).

For instance:

```
git log -n 1 -p -- hello.js
```

will show you the first commit that:

- is reachable from `HEAD`, and
- modifies file `hello.js`

and also show the diff for it (`-p`).  You can alter what comes out before the diff with `--pretty=format:...` directives.  Note that the diff will suppress other changes in the same commit, showing only those that affect the selected file(s).

Comment: Thanks but similar to the other answer, if I change `1` to `2` etc., then it shows diffs from then until the present, rather than just for one commit. Is there a way to show just for one commit?

Comment: With `-n 2` I get the most recent two commits that modified the file in question.  Same for `git show -n 2 -- <path>`.  This works even if there is a gap between such revisions (for the same reason it works for `git rev-list`: git is doing "history simplification" and then printing only commits for which the simplified result is "not TREESAME", as the documentation puts it).

Comment: Yeah so I'm wondering, is there a way to get the fifth most recent commit on a file without showing the commits that come after that one on the same file? It doesn't seem like it at the moment unfortunately, based on the two answers to this question...

Comment: There is, but not as a single git command.  The trick here is to use `git rev-list`, which is what all these commands do (well, sort of: many are built into a single binary; but the effect is the same).  It's `git rev-list` that produces the list of revs, and then `git show` or `git log -p` that shows a diff and/or other items.  So use `git rev-list` to get five interesting commits, then select the fifth such commit from the list of 5 (e.g., `| tail -1`), then provide that SHA-1 to your command of choice.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to torek's solution with `show` instead of `log` (requires less command line options):

```
git show -1 hello.js
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works, but if I do `show -2` then it shows the diffs from then until now, rather than diffs for just that one commit.

Comment: Your question states "See latest diff for a file", so my answer works for this case specifically. If you want to see the diff for a specific commit then you have to specify the commit hash instead of `-1`, i.e. `git show <hash> hello.js` (then again, this conflicts with your question "without specifying a commit signature"...).